# How can I model this water pump?

Tags: simulation, spice, fluid-pump

Consider [this object.](https://www.comet-pumpen.de/fileadmin/pdf/pumpen_datenblaetter/12v_tauchpumpen/Datenblatt_ELEGANT_1300.01.00.pdf)

How can I model it in order to simulate with a circuit simulator driving this object with a MOSFET?

I'm especially worried about inductive properties in order to avoid voltage peaks, I guess I can use an inductor with a series resistor (I guess I can calculate the resistance with the fact the maximum current is 2.2. A) but no idea on which a reasonable value for the inductor can work.

Here a basic schematic on what I mean by driving:

[image]

No PWM, just plain ON/OFF with on time a couple of minutes a day.

Comment: Depends. Is it brushed DC?

Comment: Do you want to model the electromechanical characteristics as well? Angular moment of inertia, rotor speed, output power, back-EMF, regeneration, etc?

Comment: @JohnD no just a rough electrical inductance approzimarion

Comment: @winny wo knows? The spec are the link  and nothing more

Comment: "Driving this object with a MOSFET".  That narrows things down from a big infinity to a smaller infinity -- but there's still an infinite number of circuits that could match that description.  Please _edit your question_ to show **how** you propose to do this.  I assume you want to use a high- or low-side MOSFET to just turn the pump on and off -- if so, please include your proposed schematic.

Comment: Find another 12 V motor with current rating close to 2.2 A which has inductance specified and use that? Anyhow, what will either kill your MOSFET or not will be the startup and stall behavior. With either ample MOSFET rating or overcurrent protection, your model will be superfluous. Unless you’re mass producing this, you’re better off spending time on that and a suitable flyback diode.

Comment: @TimWescott add the basic schematic